# Store description and install button missing in Google App Invites invite

Tags: google-app-invites

We integrated App Invites in our second app. In first app it was working fine. In second app, when we invite somebody on email, it sends a plain text email with install link. Store description which it used to show in email and install button are missing this time. Here is the link to the app - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ojassoft.news

Answer (score 1):

What you describe occurs when the association from the app to the play store can't be determined. For android, the association is the packageName which must match the play store apps packageName (guaranteed to match if you invite from the app downloaded from the play store). Also, this association can take as long as a day after the app is initially created in the play store.